# How to access Grails "session" from Groovy POGO?

Tags: session, grails

I have a Grails 2.3.6 app and was wondering what the scope of the `session` variable is? Will it be available, natively, to any Groovy class located under `grails-app`? If not, then say I have a particular Groovy source:

> myapp/grails-app/widgets/com/me/myorg/FizzBuzz.groovy

How do I make the current `session` object available to `FizzBuzz`, so that inside a `FizzBuzz` method I can write:

```
class FizzBuzz {
    def doSomething() {
        session.foo = "true"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really make session available to any arbitrary POGO or POJO, but you probably shouldn't anyway.  You do have options.  Your interaction with FizzBuzz probably traces back to something that does have access to the session and that thing could pass the session down the call stack so it makes its way to your FizzBuzz instance as a method argument or you could go the other way and have FizzBuzz return something and that something could contain data that needs to be put in session.

You could also do something hacky like `RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().getSession()`, or meta program a method onto FizzBuzz that does that so in the FizzBuzz class you just refer to `session`.  I don't think I would recommend that.  That could be made to work but the fact that you are trying to access web stuff directly from POGOs is probably a hint that the flow isn't really organized the way that it should be.

If you elaborate a little more on what you are doing that will help offer more specific solutions.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff Scott Brown (+1) - what would I need to import in `FizzBuzz` in order to have access to `RequestContextHolder`? And what would the `setXYZ()` method be off of `getSession()`? Something like `getSession().setFoo("true")`? Thanks again!

Comment: `import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder`.  The second part of your question about `getXYZ` and `getFoo` don't make sense to me.  Best of luck.

Comment: "You can't really make session available to any arbitrary POGO" - FYI, that was true when I wrote this answer but in recent versions of Grails one can implement the `grails.web.api.ServletAttributes` trait in any Groovy class and that Groovy class will inherit the `session` property from the trait.